# Why did my fish die?

Tags: mass-effect-2

I bought some fish in the Citadel for my cabin, fed them a few times, stared at them a bit, and did a couple of missions. When I came back from these missions, my fish were dead!

Why did the die? I've bought some more, and I've been watching them for any signs of peakishness, but they seem fine so far. How can I ensure a long lifespan for my new aquatic friends? Is my hamster in danger too?

Comment: lol +1 for a good laugh! :-)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The Mass Effect wiki suggests you need to feed them after every mission (although you can get your PA to feed them if you flirt with her and take her to dinner - I suspect this only works for male Shepherds - I don't remember being offered the option).

They are a bit silly, really.

http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Fish

Comment: Very silly (especially the hamster), but occasionally a Commander needs a distraction from saving the galaxy...

Comment: Kelly will also feed them for females, to quote: "Character matters, not race or gender."

Comment: Kelly loves *everyone*.

Comment: I played after reading this answer (having already dined with Kelly earlier in the day) thinking "How do I get her to do this, then?" And the first thing she said was "Would you like me to feed your fish when you're away? (Yes/No)"...